# InfoPath Multiple Choice Answers Muddled

Tags: vba, workspace, infopath, multiple-choice

I have an InfoPath form with approximately 80 fields within it. After updating said form to include about 20 more fields, I clicked preview and realized that the multiple choices had switched around.
For example, a tick box (Yes/No) question now has 3 tick boxes with 3 different variables from another question, which now has 2 random other variables from another drop down question.
Is there a way to ensure that my multiple choice questions will show respective answers?

Comment: Do you have code to accompany your question? It wholly depends how you referenced the form fields, as I know there are types that are referenced in order from top to bottom, so if you added fields in between, you would get a numbering error. Way better to reference them by tags.

Comment: I just dragged and dropped the fields int their respective positions.  I will look into this now.  Thanks